# Can I edit files retrieved with CheckoutPaths and push to a Remote Branch?

Tags: libgit2sharp

Without having the full clone of a branch.

Is it possible to:

- Retrieve files from a Remote Repo to a local Repo using CheckoutPaths
- Edit the files and commit in the local branch.
- Push the commit to the remote repo?

The code below commits but I am unable to find a way to push.

```cs
string result = Repository.Init(fullLocalPath);

using (var repo = new Repository(result))
{
    Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", url);

    //fetch remote
    FetchOptions fo = new FetchOptions { CredentialsProvider = (_url, _usernameFromUrl, _cred)
            => gitUserCred};
    repo.Fetch(remote.Name, fo);

    //reference fetched tracked branch.
    Branch trackedBranch = repo.Branches[trackedBranchName];

    //create a local branch
    var localBranch = repo.CreateBranch(testBranchName, trackedBranch.Tip);

    //map local to tracked.
    repo.Branches.Update(localBranch,
                    b => b.Remote = remote.Name,
                    b => b.UpstreamBranch = localBranch.CanonicalName);

    //switch to local branch
    CheckoutOptions co = new CheckoutOptions { CheckoutModifiers= CheckoutModifiers.Force };
    repo.CheckoutPaths(localBranch.Name, fileList.AsEnumerable<string>(), co);

    foreach (string file in fileList)
    {
        //change files here.
        //then stage
        repo.Stage(localFileFull);
    }

    Commit c =  repo.Commit("Persisting the files locally");

    //commit
    PushOptions po = new PushOptions();
    var pushRefSpec = $"{c.Sha}:refs/heads/master";
    po.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _usernameFromUrl, _cred) => gitUserCred;
    repo.Network.Push(remote, c.Sha, pushRefSpec, po, testSignature, "partial push");
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that you don't have a "full clone"?  What kind of error(s) do you get trying to push?